# I Get this error when im trying to execute ng serve "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies

Im Starting with Angular/cli and when I try to execute ng serve I Get this error. I've already update npm and I did cache clean --force, I've restarded  my pc and all that and still not working,
I've tryed executing globaly and in the directory itself and anything seems work, any help?

To highlight, after that error I was getting  "Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'" I've updated npm, reinstalled nodejs and install npm when I was passing trhough that but now I get this.
I'm working in windows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d7Wh.png)

Comment: You probably did not install the dependencies, run `npm install` or `yarn install` depending on your package manager.

Comment: I did it and semmed to work but now i got a blank page in the browser with "cannot GET / " and in the console " Error: The Angular compiler requires Typescript >=4.0.0 and <4.1.0 but 4.1.3 was found instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install compiler in your project `npm i @angular/compiler-cli --save`
after then `ng serve`